# Angle guessing in geometry

Tags: geometry

Is there any quick formula to answer that which one is greater, w or v? 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only a matter of how to express angles.
$v=y$, $w=x+y$.

It is obvious which angle is bigger.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Express $v, w$ in terms of $x$ and $y$. The conclusion should be immediate.

Comment: $x+y+z=180$ then $x+v+w=180$ now how to guess the value of $w$ and $v$

Comment: @mathphy Note that I didn't include $z$ in there. WHat is $v$ and $w$ in terms of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: $w=x+y$ and $v=x+z$then
$$w-y=v-z$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $w=x+y=x+v$, thus $w>v$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the line with zero slope, let $B$ be the line with positive slope.

If $A$ and $B$ were parallel, $v$ and $w$ would be equal. As drawn, $B$ tilts toward angle $v$ a bit, shrinking $v$.

$w$ is bigger.